# Configuration file for Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, configuration

I am new in Android Development.
I want to save information that only developer know, like file configuration in order to save my preference settings.
In the node.js I used **dotenv** npm that can store in the .env file.

What is the best way to do that?
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using **gradle.properties**, you can use it as a configuration file where you store key-value pairs.

1 - Create a file called gradle.properties in the app level of your project :

[image]

2- Put your key-value pairs :

```
API_DEV_KEY=AOIAPAUIKCHSLH
ENABLE_API=true
REQUEST_TIME_OUT=100
```

3 - Go to your app module **build.gradle** file and under the **defaultConfig** section add :

```
buildConfigField "String", "API_DEV_KEY", "\"${project.API_DEV_KEY}\""
buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_API", "${project.ENABLE_API}"
buildConfigField "int", "REQUEST_TIME_OUT", "${project.REQUEST_TIME_OUT}"
```

4 - Build your project.

5 - You can use the configuration properties from your code like the following:

```
int timeOut = BuildConfig.REQUEST_TIME_OUT;
String apiKey = BuildConfig.API_DEV_KEY;
boolean enableAPI = BuildConfig.ENABLE_API;
```